# Getting 401 Unauthorized while accessing Power BI API

Tags: azure, permissions, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Here's a screenshot of the API call in Postman.  I'm getting the token and using it here.

[image]

I'm getting 401 Unauthoized with no response.  Is it because of the permissions within the app registration?

I've the following permissions for  Power BI Service and Windows Azure Active Directory:
[image]
[image]

But when I click on grant permissions I get the error:

[image]

So, does the admin need to grant permission for this app (Web app / API) for it to work?

**UPDATE**

This is the API I call to get the access token.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/parkercorp.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token
```

POST BODY:

```
client_id: app_registration_clientId
client_secret: app_registration_client_secret
grant_type: client_credentials
resource: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api
scope: openid
```

This is the decoded token as suggested by Tom Sun.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> So, does the admin need to grant permission for this app (Web app / API) for it to work?

The root reason for granting permission failed is that you need admin consent that your admin can do it.

As you want to access the powerBI resource, so just need to check PowerBI service premission.

But cccording to your screenshot, you are trying to call [Get Dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/dashboards/getdashboard) API.

GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/dashboards/{dashboardKey}

Based on the document, required scope is  **Dashboard.ReadWrite.All** or **Dashboard.Read.All**. It is no need to require admin consent.

[image]

401 error means that no permission to access the resource.

We could use the [JWT.io](https://jwt.io/) to to decode the token to check the aud and permissions.

[image]

If possible, you could add the code how to get the token that will be more helpful.

Comment: I updated my question.  I'm using this endpoint to get the token:   https://login.microsoftonline.com/parkercorp.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token

Comment: Even though all the permission I granted to this app do not require an admin, but whenever I click on grant permissions I get the error saying could not grant permissions.

Comment: It seems that your app has permissions for other APIs that require admin

Comment: I don't think that's the case.  In the screenshot I provided, there is only Power BI Service and AD.

Comment: Accroding to your decode token, there is no permission about Dashboard.Read.App or Dashboard.ReadWrite.All, please have a try to add it in your scope

Comment: I have defined the scope in my request:
scope - openid.  Do I replace that?

Comment: please have a  try to add `Dashboard.ReadWrite.All` or `Dashboard.Read.All` in your scope.

Comment: Yes, I tried that but 'scp' still doesn't show up when I decode the token

Comment: @MAK did you overcome this issue? since I encountering  the same problem

Comment: @mdargacz Yes, I simply selected the permissions that required no admin.  I wanted to get all dashboards in my workspace.  The real reason why I was getting 401 was because our account was a federated and I had to use ADAL to get data from the API.

Comment: @MAK which sdk did you use?  Since  I tried to use https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples . And both NodeJs example and C# ones are showing me 401. those are the permissions https://i.imgur.com/0nTzXPG.png

Comment: @mdargacz I used the .NET SDK. Your permissions look good to me.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a permission checked that says "Requires Admin", then yes, you need an admin to click Grant Permissions. However, I don't think the two you have selected in your screenshot above are necessary for what you're trying to do. Try unchecking them, granting permissions, and running the request again.

Comment: I unchecked the 2 in Power BI Service which said 'Requires Admin' and tried to click on grant permissions but I got an error saying I wasn't authorized to grant permissions.

Comment: Does that app have permissions for other APIs that require admin?

Comment: This app is exclusive for Power BI APIs.

Comment: Your AAD tenant might have the setting on that prevents regular users from granting permissions. That means your admin must do it.

Comment: Jason, please check the answer I posted.  It was too long for a comment. @juunas